# Android Studio randomly disappears/crashes with 7GB Ram

Tags: android, random, crash, ram

i have 7GB Ram, 2GB of it as Ramdisk, 2GB Heapsize for Android Studio...

The problem is, Android Studio ramdomly disappears/crashes...

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 32-bit desktop machine I changed Android Studio's JDK from Open JDK to Oracle JDK, which fixed the random crash of my Android Studio 1.4.1. Go to -> File -> Project Structure, change the JDK, and see if it works for you as well.